# Automatic <a> around headings in Pandoc

Tags: html, hyperlink, markdown, pandoc, html-heading

This Markdown code:

```
# Introduction
```

Turns into this HTML code when compiled with Pandoc:

```
<h1 id="introduction"><a href="#introduction">Introduction</a></h1>
```

The way I use Markdown:

1. Generate HTML document
2. Edit it in MS Word to add page numbering
3. HTML version goes to blog, MS Word version goes to uni submissions

In CSS I can override link colors if they are inside H# tags, but MS Word has problems interpreting hierarchy of CSS overrides... and ends up with wrong colors anyway.

Is there a way to generate HTML without headings being wrapped in anchor tags, like below?

```
<h1 id="introduction">Introduction</h1>
```

Comment: Maybe I misread, but you realize that you can export from pandoc to word format directly?

Answer (score 0):

In case there is no solution, here is a little PHP script I wrote to remove  tags from headings that must be run on the resulting HTML file:

```
<?php
// Usage: php cleanheadings.php myhtmlfile.html

// Check that arguments were supplied
if(!isset($argv[1])) die('No input file, exiting');

// Load file
$content = file_get_contents($argv[1]);

// Cut out the <a> tag
$heading = '/(<h[123456] id="[\w-0-9]+">)(<a href="#[\w-0-9]+">)(.+)(<\/a>)(<\/h[123456])/mu';
$clean   = '$1$3$5';

$cleanhtml = preg_replace($heading,$clean,$content);

// Write changes back to file
file_put_contents($argv[1], $cleanhtml);
?>
```